# Query Fusion tables AFTER submitting UiApp custom form with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

I have designed small form using UiApp script which collects little information and after that should do a lot of Fusion tables data manipulation. I want all processing to be done after form is closed and application returned so user is not waiting for all Fusion tasks to be completed. I was planning to send data first to spreadsheet, trigger onFormSubmit and do all my Fusion tasks with trigger on onFormSubmit. But when I doPost() in UiApp apps script from my site onFormSubmit in the spreadsheet is not working. I am looking for SQL trigger like functionality to process data after record is inserted into Fusion table. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The forum submit event only fires when a user fills out a form attached to the spreadsheet. Inserting rows into the spreadsheet (or a fusion table) through Apps Script will not trigger the event. One solution is to use the [Script services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_script) to schedule a one-time trigger, which can do your offline processing.

Comment: Thank you Eric! After inserting record into Fusion table it could be necessary to use new information immediately to correctly track customers. I am not sure how small can be a reasonable time-driven trigger interval to make sure it is updated as fast as possible. Every minute? Is it acceptable? I don't feel comfortable creating so much work for web servers because a few times per day tables need to be updated instantly. If no other solution could be found, i will be using time triggers.

Comment: Time based triggers have a minimum interval of five minutes.